# Converting individual schedules in resource capacity in R

Tags: r, timestamp, schedule

I am working with R and I have these Schedules for one specific day for 3 resources (In the real data there is one of this tables for each day of the week).

```
| Resource |  start   |   end    |   status    |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ----------- |
|    C1    | 01:00:00 | 06:20:00 | unavailable |
|    C1    | 06:20:00 | 23:34:00 |  available  |
|    C1    | 23:34:00 | 00:59:59 | unavailable |
|    C2    | 01:00:00 | 03:33:00 | unavailable |
|    C2    | 03:33:00 | 22:39:00 |  available  |
|    C2    | 22:39:00 | 00:59:59 | unavailable |
|    C3    | 01:00:00 | 05:10:00 | unavailable |
|    C3    | 05:10:00 | 00:59:59 |  available  |
```

I want to convert this schedules in one table of resource capacity.
This means that I want to express for each time interval how many resources there are available. The result should look as follows.

The real data is: but in the example above I just included the resource SolverC1 and day Wednesday.

UPDATE:
In the example above I included on purpose only Solvers C1, C2 and C3. Because the availability periods should be for resources working on the same tasks. So the first 43 rows of the data should be enough for the example. The periods of unavailability should also be consider and at the end, a whole day should be represented as periods of availability (when at least one resource is available) or non-availability (when no resource is available)
In the results table I am aiming to get, you can see a day from 01:00:00 til 00:59:59 is represented. The periods of these day are disjunct and there are no periods of time missing.

```
|  start   |   end    | # of resources |  Resources |
|          |          |   available    |  available |
| -------- | -------- | -------------- | ---------- |
| 01:00:00 | 03:33:00 |        0       |            |
| 03:33:00 | 05:10:00 |        1       |      C2    |
| 05:10:00 | 06:20:00 |        2       |   C2, C3   |
| 06:20:00 | 22:39:00 |        3       | C2, C3, C1 |
| 22:39:00 | 23:34:00 |        2       |   C3, C1   |
| 23:34:00 | 00:59:59 |        1       |     C3     |
```

```
structure(list(resource = c("SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC1", 
"SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC1", 
"SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC1", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", 
"SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", 
"SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", "SolverC2", 
"SolverC2", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", 
"SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", 
"SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverC3", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", 
"SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", 
"SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", "SolverS1", 
"SolverS1", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", 
"SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", 
"SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS2", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", 
"SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", 
"SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", 
"SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "SolverS3", "System", "System", 
"System", "System", "System", "System", "System", "System", "System", 
"Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", 
"Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", "Tester1", 
"Tester1", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", 
"Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", 
"Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester2", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", 
"Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", 
"Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", "Tester3", 
"Tester3", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", 
"Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", 
"Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", "Tester4", 
"Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", 
"Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", 
"Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester5", "Tester6", "Tester6", 
"Tester6", "Tester6", "Tester6", "Tester6", "Tester6", "Tester6", 
"Tester6", "Tester6", "Tester6"), period_start = c("01:00:00", 
"01:00:00", "01:00:00", "06:20:00", "23:34:00", "01:00:00", "03:35:00", 
"01:00:00", "04:26:00", "01:00:00", "09:16:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:16:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "03:33:00", "22:39:00", "01:00:00", 
"03:07:00", "20:29:00", "01:00:00", "02:34:00", "01:00:00", "04:01:00", 
"21:35:00", "01:00:00", "04:01:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "07:38:00", 
"23:38:00", "01:00:00", "05:10:00", "01:00:00", "03:24:00", "01:00:00", 
"01:00:00", "04:18:00", "20:20:00", "01:00:00", "03:33:00", "01:00:00", 
"03:11:00", "01:00:00", "03:57:00", "01:00:00", "02:26:00", "21:34:00", 
"01:00:00", "03:56:00", "20:57:00", "01:00:00", "03:29:00", "01:00:00", 
"23:27:00", "01:00:00", "21:07:00", "01:00:00", "03:32:00", "22:30:00", 
"01:00:00", "02:12:00", "01:00:00", "02:25:00", "01:00:00", "04:35:00", 
"21:49:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:07:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:51:00", "22:28:00", "01:00:00", "04:37:00", "23:40:00", "01:00:00", 
"03:07:00", "22:14:00", "01:00:00", "06:07:00", "01:00:00", "23:30:00", 
"01:00:00", "03:15:00", "06:27:00", "01:00:00", "02:06:00", "23:11:00", 
"01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"01:00:00", "08:56:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:46:00", "22:38:00", 
"01:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:32:00", "01:00:00", "04:02:00", "01:00:00", 
"03:23:00", "01:00:00", "02:16:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:26:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "04:08:00", "22:42:00", "01:00:00", 
"01:00:00", "02:44:00", "23:32:00", "01:00:00", "03:38:00", "21:17:00", 
"01:00:00", "05:21:00", "01:00:00", "02:16:00", "23:46:00", "01:00:00", 
"01:00:00", "03:24:00", "01:00:00", "03:36:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:01", 
"01:08:00", "01:50:00", "09:04:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "22:50:00", 
"01:00:00", "03:13:00", "23:27:00", "01:00:00", "03:11:00", "22:14:00", 
"01:00:00", "02:21:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:50:00", "08:46:00", 
"01:00:00", "04:44:00", "22:52:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:46:00", 
"22:05:00", "01:00:00", "02:34:00", "23:56:00", "01:00:00", "03:20:00", 
"01:00:00", "04:10:00", "23:09:00", "01:00:00", "02:26:00", "08:38:00", 
"01:00:00", "01:00:00", "06:44:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:07:00", 
"01:00:00", "23:11:00", "01:00:00", "03:53:00", "23:30:00", "01:00:00"
), period_end = c("00:59:59", "00:59:59", "06:20:00", "23:34:00", 
"00:59:59", "03:35:00", "00:59:59", "04:26:00", "00:59:59", "09:16:00", 
"00:59:59", "00:59:59", "02:16:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "03:33:00", 
"22:39:00", "00:59:59", "03:07:00", "20:29:00", "00:59:59", "02:34:00", 
"01:08:00", "04:01:00", "21:35:00", "00:59:59", "04:01:00", "01:04:00", 
"02:24:00", "07:38:00", "23:38:00", "00:59:59", "05:10:00", "00:59:59", 
"03:24:00", "23:59:00", "00:59:59", "04:18:00", "20:20:00", "00:59:59", 
"03:33:00", "00:59:59", "03:11:00", "00:59:59", "03:57:00", "00:59:59", 
"02:26:00", "21:34:00", "00:59:59", "03:56:00", "20:57:00", "00:59:59", 
"03:29:00", "00:59:59", "23:27:00", "00:59:59", "21:07:00", "00:59:59", 
"03:32:00", "22:30:00", "00:59:59", "02:12:00", "00:59:59", "02:25:00", 
"00:59:59", "04:35:00", "21:49:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", 
"02:07:00", "00:59:59", "02:51:00", "22:28:00", "00:59:59", "04:37:00", 
"23:40:00", "00:59:59", "03:07:00", "22:14:00", "00:59:59", "06:07:00", 
"01:07:00", "23:30:00", "00:59:59", "03:15:00", "06:27:00", "00:59:59", 
"02:06:00", "23:11:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", 
"00:59:59", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "08:56:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", 
"02:46:00", "22:38:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "02:32:00", "00:59:59", 
"04:02:00", "00:59:59", "03:23:00", "00:59:59", "02:16:00", "00:59:59", 
"00:59:59", "00:59:59", "02:26:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "04:08:00", 
"22:42:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "02:44:00", "23:32:00", "00:59:59", 
"03:38:00", "21:17:00", "00:59:59", "05:21:00", "00:59:59", "02:16:00", 
"23:46:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "03:24:00", "00:59:59", "03:36:00", 
"00:59:59", "01:08:00", "01:00:00", "01:50:00", "09:04:00", "00:59:59", 
"00:59:59", "22:50:00", "00:59:59", "03:13:00", "23:27:00", "00:59:59", 
"03:11:00", "22:14:00", "00:59:59", "02:21:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", 
"02:50:00", "08:46:00", "00:59:59", "04:44:00", "22:52:00", "00:59:59", 
"00:59:59", "02:46:00", "22:05:00", "00:59:59", "02:34:00", "23:56:00", 
"00:59:59", "03:20:00", "00:59:59", "04:10:00", "23:09:00", "00:59:59", 
"02:26:00", "08:38:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "06:44:00", "00:59:59", 
"01:06:00", "02:07:00", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "00:59:59", "03:53:00", 
"23:30:00", "00:59:59", "01:01:00"), status = c("available", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "available", "available", "available", "available", 
"available", "available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "available", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"available", "available", "unknown", "unknown", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", 
"available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"unavailable", "available", "available", "unavailable", "available", 
"available", "unavailable", "unavailable", "available", "unavailable", 
"available"), day = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", 
"Sun"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c("19", "6", "1310", 
"7", "1410", "1510", "8", "2910", "16", "24", "4510", "18", "611", 
"34", "42", "5310", "29", "5410", "5510", "30", "5610", "691", 
"38", "701", "39", "711", "4910", "2710", "50", "941", "51", 
"951", "1081", "59", "1231", "66", "54", "1141", "62", "115", 
"911", "49", "1501", "78", "1381", "73", "1681", "87", "1691", 
"1701", "88", "1711", "1581", "82", "83", "161", "71", "1351", 
"1981", "102", "1991", "2141", "110", "1881", "97", "2181", "112", 
"2191", "113", "93", "210", "108", "2311", "119", "2321", "2331", 
"120", "2341", "2351", "121", "2361", "2621", "135", "1161", 
"2271", "2651", "137", "2661", "229", "118", "2301", "149", "143", 
"144", "152", "146", "1611", "162", "315", "155", "324", "167", 
"325", "168", "355", "182", "357", "183", "345", "177", "320", 
"165", "166", "200", "382", "194", "189", "399", "203", "400", 
"204", "389", "198", "390", "378", "192", "379", "413", "2101", 
"415", "211", "416", "218", "419", "213", "434", "220", "2281", 
"12372", "12373", "2291", "451", "222", "249", "487", "474", 
"243", "475", "464", "236", "465", "478", "245", "253", "496", 
"254", "497", "470", "241", "471", "259", "522", "267", "523", 
"5101", "261", "5111", "512", "262", "500", "256", "501", "543", 
"277", "544", "272", "552", "281", "282", "581", "297", "291", 
"547", "575", "293", "576", "294"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please provide your data as code, not as formated tables. You can use `dput(data)`

Comment: And please also tell how to sort the start and end variables.

Comment: Since they are timestamps I just would order them from earliest to latest. Or maybe I am not understanding your question right

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, this might help you:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(status == "available") %>% 
  group_by(week,day,period_start,period_end) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    resources = paste0(resource,collapse = ", ")
  )


# A tibble: 74 x 6
# Groups:   week, day, period_start [63]
    week day   period_start period_end     n resources                         
   <int> <ord> <chr>        <chr>      <int> <chr>                             
 1     1 Mon   01:00:00     00:59:59       4 SolverC1, System, Tester2, Tester5
 2     1 Mon   01:00:00     02:24:00       1 SolverC3                          
 3     1 Mon   01:00:00     22:50:00       1 Tester4                           
 4     1 Mon   02:16:00     00:59:59       1 SolverC2                          
 5     1 Mon   02:46:00     22:38:00       1 Tester1                           
 6     1 Mon   02:51:00     22:28:00       1 SolverS3                          
 7     1 Mon   03:11:00     00:59:59       1 SolverS1                          
 8     1 Mon   03:32:00     22:30:00       1 SolverS2                          
 9     1 Mon   05:21:00     00:59:59       1 Tester3                           
10     1 Mon   06:44:00     00:59:59       1 Tester6
```

Comment: Hi Vinicius, thank you for your help. I made an update to explain better what I am aiming to do